# Does nginx routing cover what’s after the final /

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

If I set up an nginx rule on `/`, does that also cover `/classes/User` if someone wants to abuse a POST request to that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set it up like this:

```
location / {
    ...
}
```

Then that will match every url that starts with `/` and does not match a more specific location.

You can read more about the different location matching configurations on the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Thanks Olli. Appreciate it